# Access Denied while using nodeService.getParentAssocs() in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

> I am getting this error when i am using nodeService.getParentAssocs()
>   in alfresco any idea?
>   **> Access Denied.  You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform
>   this operation.**

Comment: This is a legitimate scenario, why is this a problem for you?

Comment: don't know but it's giving for one user only.rest are working fine

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, the current user having permisson to access that particular node. Otherwise, try to run the code with `AuthenticationUtil.runAs()` . If possible share code snippet, we will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are executing by user that who may don't have the permission to access so you are getting this Access Denied
Try this code.

```
AuthenticationUtil.runAsSystem(
        new AuthenticationUtil.RunAsWork<Object>() {

            public Object doWork() throws Exception {

                // ...code to be run as Admin...
                return null;

            }
        }
);
```

please refer these docs links which defines user roles and permissions.

A user's role determines what they can and cannot do in a site. Each role has a default set of permissions.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/permissions_share.html

Alfresco uses roles to determine what a user can and cannot do in a space. These roles are associated with permissions.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/cuh-user-roles-permissions.html

please refer this question
[Run Alfresco Java code as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371993/run-alfresco-java-code-as-administrator)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the user that you use don't have the right permission on all parents. Did you try to use nodeService.getPrimaryParent ?